# Ext.button click() method

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

**ExtJS 4.1.**

Is there something like `Ext.button.click();` method on Ext.button class?

Is it possible to programmically "click" a button with one method?

Comment: Sorry if its a stupid question, but are you sure you're using ExtJS 1.1? It's just that ExtJS 2 is not supported for long time now, so it seems odd you're using 1.1;

Comment: Cannot believe such a popular event is not part of this framework! Ended up with awkward `button.getEl().dom.click()`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Or if you have an MVC structure you can fire the click event of the button, and if you're listening to the event in your controller and have an associated function it will get called.

```
button.fireEvent('click', button);
```

Comment: When you are using handler instead of click listener, you won't be able to fireEvent('click') on this component, event won't execute. So the best way is not to use handler, but use click listener + `button.fireEvent('click');` to simulate `clicking`.

Comment: That's right. It's always 'cleaner' to use listeners in my opinion.

Comment: Just an FYI this does not trigger the handler method for some reason. If that handler method is part of the button config.

Comment: is the click event still raised when the button is disabled? Because it would force you to test the disabled property to launch the associated function...

Comment: It will still get fired yes.

Comment: thanks s.webbandit..this is the reason why fireclick was not working as most of people using handler instead of listener.

Comment: If you're using `handler` instead of a `click` event, you can use `button.handler()`.

Comment: @dbrin The handler is not firing when the event listener is registered for click event, because it is vetoed according to ExtJS API doc.

"click ( this, e, eOpts ) 

Fires when this button is clicked, before the configured handler is invoked. Execution of the handler may be vetoed by returning false to this event."

Answer (score 11):

The last answer on this forum might give you more insight on how you can do that 
here they are-

```
1)Create the event code in a function and call the function from both sides: btn.on("clic", ...) and from the code you want to simulate the click.

2)Use: btnView.btnEl.dom.click();
```

from -
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?37772-Solved-Programmatically-click-an-Ext.Button

Comment: Don't think your linked sencha forum thread is actual (2008 year). But the idea about calling `click()` on DOM element is nice!

Comment: What is `dom.click();` ? Where eas it tken from?

Comment: @s.webbandit it is one of the base web api event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event

Answer (score 6):

ExtJS 4.2.1

```
Ext.get('component-id-of-extjs-button').el.dom.click();
Ext.get('toggle-button2').el.dom.click();
```

works for me.

Answer (score 2):

In case of buttons using handler, you can directly call the function of button.

Considering `button` is an Ext JS component, you can use:

```
   button.handler(button);
```

or if you want to reach a function of event 'click':

```
   button.listeners.click(button);
```

That would also work to call different button events.

Answer (score 2):

Since I needed it for many buttons, it was easier to implement an override on the button class, which adds a click function:

```
Ext.define('Ext.override.Button',{
    override:'Ext.button.Button',
    click:function() {
        this.getEl().dom.click();
    }
})
```

After this override has been added to the code base, the following works like a charm:

```
Ext.getCmp("MyButton").click()
```

Unlike fireEvent or fireHandler, this will work with all kinds of buttons - no matter whether they have a click event or a handler, or whether they are toggle buttons where the clicked button has to be marked as pressed also.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to execute the "handler" of the button, just run this (tested with ExtJS 4.2)

```
button.fireHandler()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in your test scripts, take a look at my [Ext.ux.Test library](https://market.sencha.com/users/30/extensions/121). If you need it for something other, I would suggest reconsidering your approach.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me, but i found something simplier i think :

```
var button=Ext.get('the_id_div');
button.dom.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.getElementById("someButtonId").click();
```